# Error loading images after app was deployed to heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I created a flask app that allows user to select a profile image using a selectfield provided by flask wtforms. When I was developing the app and running it locally, all the images would load fine. However after deploying the app the heroku all of the profile images do not load, even when I run it locally. I get this error message in my console:

GET https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-786085_robot-01-icon-robot-free-icon-hd-png.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

The image links are stored in my forms.py:

```
avatars = [('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-786085_robot-01-icon-robot-free-icon-hd-png.png', 'Robot'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-786416_flat-design-png-avatar-transparent-png.png', 'Dancer with Afro'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-786705_king-of-fish-avatar-clip-arts-wajah-gambar.png', 'King of Fish'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-787370_avatar-icon-storybook-unicorn-transparent-icon-unicorn-hd.png', 'Unicorn'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-787300_grim-reaper-icon-roblox-tower-warfare-hd-png.png', 'Skull'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/78-787178_picture-freeuse-computer-icons-emoticon-avatar-clip-silent.png', 'Mouth Taped Shut'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/295-2955682_findings-festival-edm-avatar-hd-png-download.png', 'Colorful Mouse'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/280-2800820_avatar-beak-beginner-black-cute-emotion-face-linux.png', 'Penguin'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/146-1468523_bear-profile-icon-png-download-transparent-png.png', 'Bear'),
('https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/30-301598_cartoon-santa-hat-free-clip-art-on-santa.png', 'Holiday Bunny'),
('https://img2.pngio.com/default-image-png-picture-710225-default-image-png-default-png-376_356.png', 'Default')]

class UserAddForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form for adding users."""

    username = StringField('Username Max 25 characters*', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email*', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password*', validators=[Length(min=6)])
    avatar = SelectField('Select an Avatar', choices=avatars)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The subdomain p in kindpng.com appears to be offline or something and it's currently unreachable hence incapable of serving GET requests.

Server status check:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow what are the odds that must have begun literally seconds between be deploying my app and running it locally, thank you so much!!